# sprintf url formatting in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, printf

how do i write a function in javascript that can get the current url eg:

http://www.blahblah.com/apps/category.php?pg=1&catId=3021

and depending on a user selection choice, appends another parameter to the url like:

http://localhost/buyamonline/apps/category.php?pg=1&catId=3021**&limit=5**

but heres the catch:

Everytime the user selects a diff choice, I dont want to keep appending stuff like

http://localhost/buyamonline/apps/category.php?pg=1&catId=3021**&limit=5&limit=10** and so on.

I want to always replace add it if there is no limit parameter or replace the value if there is one.

I was trying to accomplish this using sprintf but failed.

i was doing like so:

```
var w = document.mylimit.limiter.selectedIndex;
var url_add = document.mylimit.limiter.options[w].value;
var loc = window.location.href;
window.location.href = sprintf(loc+"%s="+%s, "&limit", url_add);
```

Comment: There is no `sprintf` in Javascript unless you write one.

Comment: i got a sprintf wrapper written by some dude http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-sprintf.html - since you understand my question, do you have any solution? thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated with regular expression solution implemented in JS.**

1. You can use a regular expression using JavaScript replace() Method
2. You can use build the entire url each time rather than just appending a parameter
3. You can parse the url into it's parts before appending the parameter

Which would you prefer?

For #1: The following should do the trick. Note though, there are issues with using regular expressions for parsing urls. (Ref: stackoverflow.com/questions/1842681/…)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var pattern = "&limit(\=[^&]*)?(?=&|$)|^foo(\=[^&]*)?(&|$)";
  var modifiers = "";
  var txt=new RegExp(pattern,modifiers);
  var str="http://localhost/buyamonline/apps/category.php?pg=1&catId=3021&limit=5";
  document.write(str+"<br/>");
  var replacement = "&limit=10";
  document.write(str.replace(txt, replacement));
</script>
```

Comment: regex with javascript replace method i think should do.

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find my **sprintf** implementation which you can use it in your JS code to achieve what you need. It works almost like the C++/Java/PHP *sprintf* function with some limitations: the format specifiers are written like `%1` and does not support the typed format specifiers (like `%d`, `%s`, `%.2f`, etc).

```
String.prototype.sprintf = function() {
  var matches,result = this, p = /%(\d)/g;
  while (matches = p.exec(result)) {
    result = result.replace(matches[0], arguments[parseInt(matches[1]) - 1]);
  }

  return result;
};
```

**Syntax**:

> `format`.*sprintf(arg1,arg2,...)*;
>
> The `format` string is composed of zero or more *format specifiers* that follows this prototype:
>
> - a `%` followed by argument index, where the first argument has index 1.
>
> The `arg1`, `arg2`, ... are the variable strings which will replace the *format specifiers*.
>
> **Example**: 'The quick `%1` fox jumps over the `%2` dog'.sprintf('`brown`','`lazy`');

**Usage example**:

```
var str = 'The size of %1 (%2) exceeds the %3 (%4).';
console.log(str.sprintf('myfile.txt', '100MB', 'max. allowed size', '75MB'));
```

**Output**:

> The size of myfile.txt (100MB) exceeds the max. allowed size (75MB).

**Note**: If you need a robust *sprintf* function then check the [sprintf](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js/blob/master/README.md) for JavaScript.